# String management in C++

Tags: c++, string

I've decided to come back to C++ after some time spent in Java and now I'm quite confused about how strings work in C++.

To start with, suppose we have a function:

```
void fun() {
   int a = 1;
   Point b(1,2);
   char c[] = "c-string";
}
```

As I understand, `a` and `b` are allocated on the stack. `c` (the pointer) is allocated on the stack too, but the contents ("c-string") live happily on the heap.

**Q1:** Are the contents of `c` automatically deallocated when the function `fun` ends?

Secondly let's suppose we have a c++ `string`:

```
void fun2() {
  (1) string s = "c++ string";
  (2) s += "append";
  (3) s = "new contents";
  (4) s = "a" + s + "c";
}
```

[String documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) isn't too specific about how the strings work, so here are the questions:

**Q2:** Are the contents of `s` automatically deallocated after `fun2` ends?

**Q3:** What does happen when we concatenate two strings? Should I care about memory usage? (line 2)

**Q4:** What happens when we overwrite the contents of a string (line 3) - what about memory, should I worry? Is the originally allocated space reused?

**Q5:** What if I construct a string like this (line 4). Is it expensive? Are string literals (`"a"`,`"c"`) pooled (like in Java) or repeated throughout the final executable?

What I am ultimately trying to learn is how to correctly use strings in C++.

Thanks for reading this,
Queequeg

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. "c-string" will be copied into `c` and the characters will reside on the stack there.

Comment: and if it was `char* c = "now what";` ?

Comment: A lot of this seems a bit on the side of premature optimization. For example, Q5 has no direct answer, but we shouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: @Queequeg explained in my answer.

Comment: If c was a pointer, it would point to some read-only location (so it should be `const char *`) where the  string is stored (which is for the life of the program).

Comment: cplusplus.com isn't considered a reputable source of documentation. Try en.cppreference.com instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As I understand, a and b are allocated on the stack. c (the pointer) is allocated on the stack too, but the contents ("c-string") live happily on the heap.

That's wrong, they all live in automatic memory (the stack). Even the `char` array. In C++, a string is an object of type `std::string`.

> Q1: Are the contents of c automatically deallocated when the function fun ends?

Yes.

> Q2: Are the contents of s automatically deallocated after fun2 ends?

Yes.

> Q3: What does happen when we concatenate two strings? Should I care about memory usage? (line 2)

They are concatenated, and the memory is managed automatically. (assuming we're talking about `std::string` and not `char[]` or `char*`.

> Q4: What happens when we overwrite the contents of a string (line 3) - what about memory, should I worry? Is the originally allocated space reused?

Implementation detail. It can be reused, it can be re-allocated if the previous memory can't hold the new contents.

> Q5: What if I construct a string like this (line 4). Is it expensive? Are string literals ("a","c") pooled (like in Java) or repeated throughout the final executable?

String literals **can** be pooled, but it's not required. For large concatenation, it's usual to use a `std::stringstream` instead (similar to Java). But profile first, don't do premature optimizations. Not that neither of those are string literals though.

```
char* pStr = "this is a string literal";
```

This resides in read-only memory and can't be modified.

> What I am ultimately trying to learn is how to correctly use strings in C++.

Use a `std::string`.

Comment: @Queequeg no it is not, you assign it to a pointer, but it is actually a `const char[N]`

Comment: So basically, the programmer *consciousness* of strings (std::string) in C++ should be more Java-ish than C-ish, correct? Meaning that I should add (e.g. string path = dir + file + extension) whenever I need and dont worry that much about memory etc?

Comment: Secondly, if I write `string x = a+b+c;` then 2 concatenations will take place and only then will the `x` string be constructed? And the two intermediate strings? What about them?

Comment: @Queequeg Those intermediate strings will be constructed and allocate/deallocate memory each. This most probably would not be a performance bottleneck, so you should not worry. If it is, you can do something like `string x; x.reserve(a.size() + b.size() + c.size()); x+=a; x+=b; x+=c;`. This would result in only one allocation.

Comment: @Queequeg pStr is a pointer and you can re-assign it, but it points to constant memory. So `pStr[0] = 'a'` would be illegal.

Comment: But it is possible to change single chars in a string (even c-string), right? I'd just have to allocate and manage it myself (malloc, copy literal and then play around).

Comment: @Queequeg yes, only a string literal disallows this. If you have a `std::string` or a `char[]` it's totally legal. (i.e. you don't even need to allocate it with `new` - `malloc` is for C, not C++)

Answer (score 8):

**`c` is not a pointer.** It is an *array*. You can tell that it's an array because it has square brackets, while pointers have a star. Since `c` is an automatic variable, it does not require any manual lifetime or memory management.

Ad Q2: `s` is also an automatic variable, and since it is of a well-designed class type, this means you don't need to take care of anything manually.

Ad Q3: Local string objects are suitably modified to contain the new string; in the process, there may or may not exist temporary string objects for the duration of the concatenation expression. (This applies only to line 4; there's no temporary in line 2.)

Ad Q4: Everything is fine and works as expected; see Q2. The original memory may or may no be used, depending on the details of the assignment. In your example, the original memory would probably be overwritten; in a case like `s = std::string("hello");`, the buffers of the two strings would probably be swapped.

Ad Q5: String literals are read-only global constants, which the compiler may implement any way it likes. The details are not so important; you will definitely end up with the desired `string` object in `s`. See Q3 re temporary objects.

To "learn how to use strings in C++", just go and use them. Treat them like integers. It'll be correct. The beauty of the standard library is that you really don't need to know "how things work"; when you use standard library classes in an idiomatic C++ fashion, all resource management is done automatically and efficiently for you.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Yes, it is de-allocated. The character array resides on the functions's stack.

Q2: Yes, `std::string` takes care of releasing all of its resources on destruction, which happens on leaving scope, as it does for all automatically allocated variables.

Q3: No, you should not worry, unless profiling tells you you should.

Q4: You should not worry, and the original space may or may not be re-used. In any case, all space used by the strings is de-allocated on exiting the function.

Q5: Given the optimizations the compiler is allowed to make the only way to determining for sure whether X is more expensive than Y is to profile both of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1** Should to note that literals `"c++ string","append","new contents","a","c"` are in static memory

Comment: Is this actually guaranteed or is the compiler allowed to make optimizations when creating `std::string` objects from literals? I am not sure that every string literal in the TU has to be present in static memory.

Comment: @KillianDS You're right, I test with a small piece of code. `"a"` and `"b"` cannot be found with `strings`. Delete my answer. And I'm now trying to find something to ref.

Comment: statement `string s = "c++ string";` will implicitly call `std::string (const char*)` constructor. But before it literal will be placed in static memory. With concatenation is the same.

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea i think this behaviour is compiler dependent.